# How to change the places of numbers in list, python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I have list, ex. [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7]
And if there is “0” I have to put it at the end of the list, without changing the places of other numbers.
Should return - [1,3,2,6,7,0,0]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to the site! I would recommend trying to let us know what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just sort by zeroness:

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7]
>>> a.sort(key=bool, reverse=True)
>>> a
[1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7] 
count = my_list.count(0)

my_list = [value for value in my_list if value != 0]
my_list.extend([0]*count)
print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it that is different than the answers so far. This will work whether it is 0 or another number that you need the same operation for (as long as you replace the 0 with the number you want in both the `filter` functions).

```
lst = [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7]
[*filter((0).__ne__, lst)] + [*filter((0).__eq__, lst)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an easier way, but here is what I came up with:

```
l = [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7]
le = len(l)
l = [x for x in l if x !=0]
for i in range(0,le-len(l)):
    l.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic programming exercice so lets approach it with the most basic Python constructs.  A simple algorithm would be to track an index where the first zero is detected and swap non-zero numbers with that position which we then move forward.  This will carry the zeroes across the list until all the zeroes are bunched up at then end.

```
numbers   = [1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7]

firstZero = -1                           # track position of first zero
for index,number in enumerate(numbers):  # go through numbers in list
    if firstZero < 0:                    
        if number == 0:                  # do nothing until a zero is found
            firstZero = index            # start tracking first zero position
    elif number != 0:
        numbers[firstZero] = number      # swap non-zero numbers
        numbers[index]     = 0           # with zero position
        firstZero         += 1           # and advance first zero position

print(numbers)
# [1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

Tracing the progress of the loop, you can see the movement of the firstZero position relative to the index and the carrying of the zeroes through the list:

```
# firstZero index number   numbers
#     -1      0     1      [1,  3,  0,  2,  6,  0,  7] # do nothing
#                        Z  ^
#     -1      1     3      [1,  3,  0,  2,  6,  0,  7] # do nothing
#                        Z   ...^
#      2      2     0      [1,  3,  0   2,  6,  0,  7] # record position of 1st zero
#                         ..........Z^
#      3      3     2      [1,  3,  2<->0,  6,  0,  7] # swap non-zero (2), 
#                                    ...Z^             # advance position of 1st zero
#      4      4     6      [1,  3,  2,  6<->0,  0,  7] # swap non-zero (6),
#                                        ...Z^         # advance position of 1st zero
#      4      5     0      [1,  3,  2,  6,  0,  0,  7] # ignore subsequent zeroes 
#                                           Z ..^      # do nothing 
#      5      6     0      [1,  3,  2,  6,  7<- 0,->0] # swap non-zero (7),
#                                            ...Z ..^  # advance position of 1st zero
```

On the other hand, if you're into more meta trickery, you can leverage the stability of the Python sort and its ability to sort on a calculated key to group the numbers between non-zeroes and zeroes:

```
numbers.sort(numbers,key=lambda n:not n)
```

The key parameter uses a function to obtain a key to sort on (as opposed to the numbers themselves).  That function here is `not n` which, when applied to an integer, will return True if it is zero and False if it is not.  This will match sorting keys with numbers in the following way:

```
 False, False, True, False, False, True, False
[1,     3,     0,    2,     6,     0,    7]
```

Sorting boolean values will place False values before True and the stability of the Python sort will keep the relative order of items for identical key values:

```
 False, False, False, False, False True, True
[1,     3,     2,     6,     7,    0,    0]
```

The calculated key values only exist during the sort process, the result is only the number list sorted accordingly.

Although using the sort function is a nice trick, in therms of complexity, it will perform in O(n log n) time.  The basic algorithm being more specialized is able to do the same work in a single pass through the data which will perform in O(n) time.

Another way to group the zeroes at the end of the list in O(n) time is to build a new list  by assembling a list of the non-zero items with a list of zeros of the appropriate length:

```
nonZero = [*filter(bool,numbers)]
numbers = nonZero + [0]*(len(numbers)-len(nonZero))
```

Then `nonZero` list is built using a list comprehension with unpacking of the result from the filter iterator.  The second part is a repetition of a list with zero for the number of times needed to reach the original length.